# DSpace , using html in hint tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml, dspace

```
<hint>I want to two line like that <br> But it doesn't work.</hint>
```

How can I add html code in hint tag in input-form.xml / DSpace .
Or can anyone do two like hint?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

(For xmlui) You could customize the [DescribeStep](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/master/dspace-xmlui/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/xmlui/aspect/submission/submit/DescribeStep.java#L1279) class to make a Message with the hint. Then instead of inserting the html in the hint-tag you'd give the message key. In the message.xml file you can add messages that contain html.